# Two .htaccess Two Sites

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, e-commerce

I have a custom ecommerce site which have one `.htaccess` file. I am now creating a blog for it using Wordpress, and installed it in a subdirectory named `blog`.

Everything was fine until I logged in to the Wordpress admin panel and changed the permalink structure to `%postname%`. After I changed it, the login page and the `.htaccess` was empty.

I need help from someone to review both my `.htacess` files and make changes which make allow the Wordpress permalink structure and make sure it doesn't conflict with the main site. If i add the Wordpress `.htaccess` code into the root `.htaccess` at the bottom, then the blog works fine but the main site gets a 404 error.

Root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Home index.php
RewriteRule ^CompanyProfile about.php
RewriteRule ^ContactUs contact.php
RewriteRule ^Shopping-Basket inq.php
RewriteRule ^My-Account myacc.php
RewriteRule ^SiteMap sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^Terms-Conditions terms.php
RewriteRule ^Privacy-Policy privacy.php
RewriteRule ^Delivery-Information delivery.php
RewriteRule ^Returns-Policy returns.php
RewriteRule ^Disclaimer disclaimer.php
RewriteRule ^Clients clients.php

RewriteRule ^Search-Results result.php
RewriteRule ^Do-Login dologin.php
RewriteRule ^Member-Login login.php
RewriteRule ^Logout logout.php
RewriteRule ^Delete/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ delp.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^Shopping-Basket/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ inq.php?msg=$1
RewriteRule ^ForgetPassword/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ forget.php?msg=$1
RewriteRule ^ForgetPassword forget.php
RewriteRule ^Checkout checkout.php
RewriteRule ^OrderStatus status.php
RewriteRule ^ChangePassword changepassword.php
RewriteRule ^CreateAccount/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ create.php?msg=$1
RewriteRule ^CreateAccount create.php
RewriteRule ^ChangeAccount chgaccount.php
RewriteRule ^Shipping shipping.php
RewriteRule ^SaveLogin savelogin.php
RewriteRule ^SaveOrder saveorder.php

RewriteRule ^sections/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ cproducts.php?SID=$2&MID=$1
RewriteRule ^bproducts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products.php?MID=$1
RewriteRule ^productdetail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ prod_detail.php?PID=$1
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ bproducts.php?SID=$2&MID=$1
RewriteRule ^Details/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ large.php?PID=$3&SID=$2&MID=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301
```

Sub-directory /blog .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Got the Solution.... 

'<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>'
add these into root .httaccess and everything works perfectly....

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question, please write an answer and accept it :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2729

Comment: I already write it in above mentioned reply. :)

Comment: You wrote a comment, not an answer. For the community, this question remains unanswered

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteBase /blog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```